# Setting segment registers after ORG instruction

Tags: nasm, x86-16, cpu-registers, segment, memory-segmentation

I am currently following [a tutorial on OS development](http://brokenthorn.com/Resources/OSDev4.html), which includes a discussion on bootloaders.

My bootloader is currently in 16-bit real mode, therefore, I am able to use the BIOS interrupts provided (e.g. VGA video interrupts, etc.).

The BIOS provides the video interrupt `0x10` (i.e. video teletype output). The video interrupt has the function `0x0E`, which allows me to print a character to the screen.

Here is this basic bootloader:

```
org     0x7c00              ; Set program start (origin) address location at 0x7c00.
                            ; This program is loaded by the BIOS at 0x7c00.
bits    16                  ; We live in 16-bit Real Mode.

start:  
        jmp loader

bootmsg     db      "Welcome to my Operating System!", 0        ; My data string.

;-------------------------------------------------------
;   Description:    Print a null terminating string
;-------------------------------------------------------
print:
    lodsb                   ; Load string byte at address DS:SI and place in AL.
                            ; Then, increment/decrement SI as defined by the Direction Flag (DF) in FLAGS.
    or      al, al          ; Set the zero flag - is AL zero?
    jz      printdone       ; Check if this is the null byte
    mov     ah, 0eh
    int     10h
    jmp     print
printdone:
    ret

loader:
    ;|---------- Related to my question ----------|
        xor     ax, ax
        mov     ds, ax
        mov     es, ax
    ;|--------------------------------------------|

    mov     si, bootmsg
    call    print

    cli                     ; Clears all interrupts.
    hlt                     ; Halts the system.

times 510 - ($-$$) db 0    ; Make sure our bootloader is 512 bytes large. 

dw      0xAA55              ; Boot signature - Byte 511 is 0xAA and Byte 512 is 0x55, indicated a bootable disk.1
```

As shown in the above code, I have highlighted the following three lines:

```
xor     ax, ax
mov     ds, ax
mov     es, ax
```

According to the original source, it says the following:

> Setup segments to insure they are 0. Remember that we have ORG 0x7c00. This means all addresses are based from 0x7c00:0. Because the data segments are within the same code segment, null em.

I am a bit confused. From my understanding, the `org` instruction tells the loader to load this program at address `0x7c00`. Why don't we take this as our start address then? Meaning, our two overlapping Data and Code segments are **not** located at a *base address* of zero. The *base address* should be 0x7c0. **Why does the author set the base address to 0x0?**

```
mov ax, 07c0h
mov dx, ax
mov es, ax
```

Comment: `org` tells the assembler the `offset` part of a `seg:off` address to assume when generating `[disp16]` addressing modes and so on (which are relative to a segment base).  If you set the segment base to `0x7c0`, you'd use `org 0`.

Comment: @PeterCordes I thought the offset was stored in the general purpose registers? Like for the `lodsb` instruction, it uses `DS:SI` - `DS` as the base address and `SI` as the offset.  Sure, `SI` is equal to the address of our string and it works out (i.e. `0000:07c0`), but the actual code is at `0x7c00`! Meaning, the base address should be 0x7c0, because the code and data segment start there. The base address marks the start of a segment. I don't understand how `org` sets the offset part. Where is that offset stored?

Comment: Dan, when you assemble `mov     si, bootmsg` the assembler will determine the address of `bootmsg`. If you use an `org` of 0 then the offset of bootmsg will be computed to be 0x0000+small offset to bootmsg. If it was `org 0x7c00` then `bootmsg` would be calculated to be 0x7c00+small offset to bootmsg. That absolute near address is stored in the instruction encoding itself.If you use NDISASM with `-b16` option you can actually take a look at how the encoding is different with and with different ORG values.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Yeah, I figure things out after doing more research. I am posted a follow up answer. Thanks for your help nonetheless.

Comment: The comment you quoted from another code base is entirely wrong.Whoever wrote it didn't know what they were talking about. A lot of people really don't understand realmode segment:offset addressing and how it relates to assembly code and origin (ORG). Starman's guide is a good resource: https://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/debug/Segments.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been looking into the `org` instruction more and other documentation and I understand what is going on.

According to the [NASM documentation](https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc7.html#section-7.1.1) on the `org` directive, short for **or**i**g**in:

> The function of the ORG directive is to specify the origin address which NASM will assume the program begins at when it is loaded into memory. [...] NASM's ORG does exactly what the directive says: origin. Its sole function is to specify one offset which is added to all internal address references within the section.

Therefore, the NASM compiler assumes that the program will be loaded at the address specified with the origin instruction (i.e. `org`). The BIOS does exactly this. According to [the following](https://wiki.osdev.org/Boot_Sequence), once the BIOS finds a valid boot sector that contains a valid boot signature, the bootloader will be "*loaded into memory at 0x0000:0x7c00 (segment 0, address 0x7c00)*."

From the quote above, when the NASM documentation says "internal address references," it is referring to all references to concrete memory regions that are being used in the code (e.g. referencing a label, etc.). For example, the line in the bootloader code above: `mov si, bootmsg` will resolve `bootmsg` to `0x07c00 + offset`, where the offset is determined by the position of the first byte of my string `bootmsg` (i.e. 'W').

With my code above, if I disassembly the bin file using the [ndisasm utility](https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoca.html) I see the following:

```
00000000  EB2C              jmp short 0x2e
00000002  57                
00000003  656C              
00000005  636F6D            
00000008  6520746F          
0000000C  206D79            
0000000F  204F70            
00000012  657261            
00000015  7469              
00000017  6E                
00000018  67205379          
0000001C  7374              
0000001E  656D              
00000020  2100              
00000022  AC                lodsb
00000023  08C0              or al,al
00000025  7406              jz 0x2d
00000027  B40E              mov ah,0xe
00000029  CD10              int 0x10
0000002B  EBF5              jmp short 0x22
0000002D  C3                ret
0000002E  31C0              xor ax,ax
00000030  8ED8              mov ds,ax
00000032  8EC0              mov es,ax
00000034  BE027C            mov si,0x7c02
00000037  E8E8FF            call 0x22
0000003A  FA                cli
0000003B  F4                hlt
00000...  ...               ...
```

*(I removed the generated instructions from 0x00000002 to 0x00000020, because that is my `bootmsg` string and is representing data, not code).*

As we can see from the output assembly, at the address 0x00000034, my `bootmsg` has been replaced with 0x7c02 (e.g. 0x7c00 + offset=0x02).

[Michael Petch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54045259/setting-segment-registers-after-org-instruction?noredirect=1#comment94930637_54045259) provided some very solid insight too. It is a common misconception to think the bootloader is loaded to 0x7c0:0x0000 (segment 0x07c0, offset 0). Although one could technically use this, it has been standardized to use the segment offset of zero instead ([A good practice is to enforce CS:IP at the very start of your boot sector](https://wiki.osdev.org/Boot_Sequence)). As Michael has mentioned, if one wants more information, look at section 4 of the following [guide on segment offset addressing](https://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/debug/Segments.html).

Comment: You can get `nasm` to give you a listing instead of having to use `ndisasm` separately.  e.g. `nasm -fbin  -l/dev/stdout  foo.asm  | less` will write the listing to the terminal.  One advantage is that it won't try to disassemble data, because it has the source.  And BTW, if you put your code first and data 2nd, you don't have to jump over the first instruction.

Comment: May you please clarify what you mean by "enfore cs:ip?" The linked source does not elaborate on what 'enforce' means.

Comment: Ah, nevermind. I see now that "0x0:0x7c00" is precisely the same address as "0x7c0:0x0", and that "enforce cs:ip" simply means that the if the programmer wishes, she may have the first instruction of her bootloader be ```jmp 0x0000:start```, assuming that she has chosen to address her code relative to 0x7c00 (or an alternative scheme if she prefers 0-relative addressing)